# Best way to periodically fetch data from server

Tags: android

I am writing an Android application where I need to periodically (every 30 seconds) fetch data from the server. I was thinking about using `AlarmManager` to schedule those tasks, however I need to be able to pass a callback function that updates the view. Since the `Intent` cannot encapsulate a callback, I decided to find another solution, which was a "worker thread". The problem here is that the request to the server is performed in `AsyncTask` where `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` have to be running from the Ui thread, so I really cannot do it this way either.

I would appreciate any suggestions what would be the best approach in this case.

Comment: But doInBackground running in its own thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Handler`.

```
 Handler mHandler;
  public void useHandler() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30000);
  }

  private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      Log.e("Handlers", "Call asynctask");
      /** Call your AsyncTask here **/
      mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 30000);
    }
  };
```